# How to configure servlet resouceTypes in OSGI annotation

Tags: osgi, aem

In the Felix annotation the Servlet code is as follows :
sling.servlet.resourceTypes is given as unbounded = PropertyUnbounded.ARRAY

```
@Component(metatype = true, label = "Test Servlet", description = "Test Servlet", configurationFactory = true, policy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE)
@Service
@Properties({
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.resourceTypes", unbounded = PropertyUnbounded.ARRAY, label = "Sling Resource Type", description = "Sling Resource Type for the Home Page component or components."),
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.selectors", value = "test-selector", propertyPrivate = true),
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.extensions", value = "html", propertyPrivate = true),
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = "GET", propertyPrivate = true) })
```

But when I am changing it to OSGI annotation as follows then I could not find a way how to initialise this sling.servlet.resourceTypes within @Component annotation

```
@Designate(ocd = TestServlet.Config.class)
@Component(name = "com.myproject.TestServlet", service = Servlet.class, property = {
    "service.description=Test Servlet", "sling.servlet.methods=GET",
    "sling.servlet.resourceTypes=" + ??, "sling.servlet.extensions=" + "html",
    "sling.servlet.selectors=" + "test-selector" }
)        
public final class TestServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {
 private String[] allowedResourceTypes;

 @Activate
protected void activate(Config config) {
       this.config = config;
       allowedResourceTypes = config.getResourceTypes();
       }

@ObjectClassDefinition(name="Test servlet config")
   public @interface Config {

     @AttributeDefinition(
                name = "Resource Types",
                description = "The set of resource types.",
                type = AttributeType.STRING
        )
        String[] getResourceTypes() ;
  }
}
```

**Update:** I could not find easy solution than registering  through code. An example could be [core Adaptive component](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/bundles/core/src/main/java/com/adobe/cq/wcm/core/components/internal/servlets/AdaptiveImageServletMappingConfigurationConsumer.java)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have multiple resource types (meaning basically an array of resource types) you have to name each one independently:

```
@Designate(ocd = TestServlet.Config.class)
@Component(
  name = "com.myproject.TestServlet", 
  service = Servlet.class, property = {
    "service.description=Test Servlet", 
    "sling.servlet.methods=GET",
    "sling.servlet.resourceTypes=nt:file", 
    "sling.servlet.resourceTypes=project/components/mycomp", 
    "sling.servlet.extensions=html",
    "sling.servlet.selectors=" + "test-selector" 
  }
)        
public final class TestServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {
 private String[] allowedResourceTypes;

 @Activate
protected void activate(Config config) {
       this.config = config;
       allowedResourceTypes = config.getResourceTypes();
       }

@ObjectClassDefinition(name="Test servlet config")
   public @interface Config {

     @AttributeDefinition(
                name = "Resource Types",
                description = "The set of resource types.",
                type = AttributeType.STRING
        )
        String[] getResourceTypes() ;
  }
}
```

So the trick is to have multiple *sling.servlet.resourceTypes* entries.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This example doesn't do anything with the OCD configuration values to the actual Servlet initialization. The `@Activate` is called after servlet is initialized with the given ResourceTypes, not exactly sure if it can be updated or how to update it once initialized,

Comment: @HasinthaAbeykoon Maybe you check the code again. The activate method is only there to *read* the valid resource types and make them available in a test that helps to see if you did the definition correct. It does *not* change the definition. 
The questions was, how a servelt can be defined to accept multiple resource types, which is done and shown in the Component annotation.
So please do not downvote answers if you do not understand the code in the question in the first place.